# Massive off-screen rendering performance drop under iOS10/11 compared to iOS9 (OGLES2.0)

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, opengl-es, fragment-shader

Background: Our in-development game took a performance nose-dive on devices we updated to iOS 10 or 11. Two iPhone 6s's running 10.3.3 would only hit 20-30fps, while an iPhone 5s still running 8.0 breezed along at 60fps.

More recently I updated an iPod6 from ios 9 to ios 11, and it too dropped from 60 to 20-30 fps running the exact same build of the game.

**NB: Initially the GPU profiler led me to believe this was a shader-related issue, but that was a false trail. Thanks to all who commented on that basis.**

Here's how I've narrowed the problem down:

Running normally, our game generates the following off-screen textures each frame:

- Ten player shadows at 256x256 (no alpha blending involved)
- Eleven 128x256 to 256x256 animating 'TV screen' textures
- A 256x512 'world reflection' texture incorporating a small subset of the models in the scene.

On the iPhone5s all this happens at a smooth 60fps. On the iPod6 and iPhone6s, since updating to iOS10/11, it struggles to hit 30fps.

As a test, I redirected all the offscreen rendering to the main framebuffer, disabled depth checking and enabled alpha blending on everything to ensure nothing would get optimised away by the tile renderer.

The upshot is that the game is forced to render over ten times the number of pixels as before (because the renders that filled a 256x256 texture now all fill a 640x1136 screen), all with alpha blending on (where before a lot of it had no blending), and it happily does this at 60fps on the iPod6.

I'm aware that there are optimisations I can still make to the off-screen rendering (I'm currently not tagging the depth-buffer on the shadow texture for discard) but that's not really the point: the 5s is handling the un-optimised render just fine, and the iPod6 used to as well, so what's changed under iOS 10/11?

Steps to reproduce:

- Generate 20 small (256x256) textures and assign them framebuffers.
- Each frame, render a few sprites to each texture, and then render the textures to the screen.
- OpenGL profile this setup.
- Redirect all the sprite rendering to the screen (but leave the 'render the textures to the screen' step in place as well)
- Profile this setup. In my tests, the second setup is as much as 10ms quicker despite the sprite rendering having to cover a much larger number of pixels.

Comment: You're talking about opengl-es, right? Which version are you targeting?

Comment: OGLES2.0 - adding to main post now.

Comment: Couple of things to try: 1. Replace the vec4 texcoord with two separate vec2s, you can avoid dependent texture reads that way (although they're not so bad on newer hardware). 2. Use a temporary vec4 instead of writing /modifying gl_FragColor multiple times.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm pretty much convinced the problem isn't what the profiler tells me, though, given that when I strip this shader back to a single line, the profiler says all the other shaders get 4 times slower.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm pretty much convinced the problem isn't what the profiler tells me, though, given that when I strip this shader back to a single line, the profiler says all the other shaders get 4 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my tests, it appears that certain iOS OGLES implementations (notably 10.3.3 and 11) do a strictly worse job of optimising interleaved renders to the screen and off-screen textures.

Ideally<sup>(1)</sup>, from the perspective of rendering to multiple destinations during a frame on tile-based hardware, an OpenGL implementation would defer executing rendering commands upon the primary framebuffer for as long as possible, with the effect of de-interleaving this *requested* sequence:

- Draw to main framebuffer
- Draw to texture 1
- Draw texture 1 to main framebuffer
- Draw to texture 2
- ...
- Draw texture n to main framebuffer

into this visually equivalent *executed* sequence:

- Draw to texture 1
- Draw to texture 2
- ...
- Draw to texture n
- Draw texture 1 to main framebuffer
- Draw texture 2 to main framebuffer
- ...
- Draw texture n to main framebuffer

The latter sequence is far more efficient as it avoids the need for repeated logical loads and stores<sup>(2)</sup> of the contents of the main framebuffer.

However, it is apparent from a simple benchmark test that the implementation in more recent versions of iOS is profoundly worse at performing this optimisation than in the past.

My benchmark allocated ten 256x256 textures and ten 512x512 textures and assigned each of them a frame buffer. Each frame it would then draw a number of large alpha-blended sprites to each texture, and then render those textures to the screen (also alpha-blended). I set it up so that it would do so in interleaved order by default, and then de-interleaved when the screen is touched.

Here are the untouched / touched (difference) results across a range of devices tested:

- iPhone 5s (iOS 8.0)  : 14ms / 11.5ms (2.5ms)
- iPod 6gen (iOS11)    : 19ms / 11.8ms (7.2ms)
- iPhone6s (iOS10.3.3) : 17ms / 8.2ms (8.8ms)

As you can see, all devices benefited from manually correcting the render order. However, the penalty of not doing so rose from 2.5ms under iOS8 to a whopping 7.2ms under iOS11 on similar hardware (prior to installing iOS11 on the iPod it ran our game smoothly, so I feel justified drawing that inference). On the iPhone6s the penalty is even higher, no doubt because of the larger screen resolution.

It seems likely that the penalty is partly attributable to logical loads and stores, and partly to stalls introduced by dependencies between finishing the render to a texture before it can be drawn to the screen. Again: in an implementation that defers commands directed to the main framebuffer, those stalls would not occur.

**Rejected Alternatives**

*Logical loads and stores have themselves increased substantially in cost.*

This would account for the observed slowdown, but not for the similarity in performance between the iPod and iPhone5s when the render order is manually de-interleaved. The corrected order still entails a good deal of logical storing (10mb) and there's no evidence of significant extra cost.

References:

1: https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-2-how-to-correctly-handle-framebuffers

2: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html

Comment: I did, but I doubt there's much appetite for fixing it given that they're deprecating OGL support :/